# Measuring distances between the stars

Tags: spacetime, astronomy, curvature, estimation, error-analysis

If we know how far away are the two known stars from Earth, then is it a safe bet that we can know how far apart those two stars are from each other using sine rules? Does that mean we must first assumed curvature of space-time is flat or from the calculation of the position of the stars we can then inferred the shape of the space-time?

Comment: Not clear what the question is. If the space is Euclidean we can use Euclidean geometry. If it isn't then we can't. Are you asking how spacetime curvature is inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nearby stars (i.e. anything in our own galaxy) we can ignore the curvature of space and the calculation is straightforward - if we know the lengths of two sides of a triangle and the angle between those sides then simple trigonometry gives us the length of the third side.

For objects that are far enough away that the curvature of space becomes significant, then (a) the whole notion of distance between two objects becomes more complicated, since we could be observing these objects at very different epochs due to the finite speed of light and (b) any correction due to the curvature of space is marginal compared to the uncertainties in our estimates of cosmic distances at this range, which are only accurate to $\pm 5 \%$ at the very best (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder)).

> From the calculation of the position of the stars can we infer the shape of space-time ?

Not by calculating the distances between pairs of objects, but instead by estimating the distances to many, many objects (galaxies or galaxy clusters) and then comparing the number of objects at various distance ranges with the number we would expect to see if the universe were not expanding.